# Parameter specified as non-null is null for data in onActivityResult

Tags: android-intent, kotlin

I'm having the same issue as described here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/437

But I'm unable to solve it with the obvious solution, which is to change the signature to

`override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {}`

because then it says that the function overrides nothing (in the original method, data is not nullable)

But without this, data is sent in as null, which is not allowed. I get the following RuntimeException:

Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {...MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data

How can I get data to not be null, or to be allowed to be null? I am pressing the "back" button in my own activity, so I am able to send in whatever I need. I've tried adding an intent with some data, i.e.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    val i = Intent()
    i.putExtra("nonNull", "nonNull")
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, i)
    finish()
}
```

Comment: What does your MainActivity extend (e.g. AppCompatActivity)? Making the intent nullable when overriding onActivityResult works for me.

Comment: My MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity, which extends Activity, so I can't change it.

Comment: Works fine for me when extending YouTubeBaseActivity. Maybe an issue with the Kotlin plugin for AS? I use Version: 1.1.4-release-Studio2.3-3.

Comment: 1.1.51-release and i still get onActivityResult overrides nothing :(

Comment: The override of onActivityResult  with nullable data param works for me with Kotlin version '1.2.41' in fragment extending from android.support.v4.app.Fragment